# I am unable to get the list of services with in the applicaton i.e.; wso2 governance registry? I am working with binary code

Tags: wso2

I am trying to get the list of services which are in the resource path /_system/governance/trunk/services. So initially I am trying to get the resource using registry api. I tried in two ways. one way is

```
         `CarbonContext cCtx = CarbonContext.getCurrentContext();

          Registry registry = cCtx.getRegistry(RegistryType.SYSTEM_CONFIGURATION);
          String registryType = request.getParameter("registryType");
          if(registryType != null) {
          registry = cCtx.getRegistry(RegistryType.valueOf(registryType));
          }
          String resourcePath = "/_system/governance/trunk/services";
          try{
      if(registry.resourceExits(resourcePath)){
        Resource resource = registry.get(resourcePath);
      }
      }catch(Exception e){
       out.print(e.getMessage());
      }`
```

Another way using ServiceManager and I am failing at the first step to initialize ServiceManager

```
            'CarbonContext cCtx = CarbonContext.getCurrentContext();

             Registry registry = cCtx.getRegistry(RegistryType.SYSTEM_CONFIGURATION);
             String registryType = request.getParameter("registryType");
             if(registryType != null) {
                   registry = cCtx.getRegistry(RegistryType.valueOf(registryType));
               out.print(" Registry got Initialised ! ");
             }
        java.util.List<Resource> result = new java.util.ArrayList<Resource>();
        String resourcePath = "/_system/governance/trunk/services";
        ServiceManager serviceManager = new ServiceManager(registry);'
```

So what's the exact thing I need to do get list of all service in index.jsp and I am working with the binary code ?

Comment: Are you hosting this webapp in the Carbon servers? If not you need to get Registry instance using WSRegistry Client.

Comment: I am hosting the webapp on the server thats coming with the binary code(wso2greg-4.5.3), so running it locally, by running wso2server.bat file. Is it fine or what do you recommend ?

Comment: I am intializing the Registry with in the web app.

Comment: Can you post the error that you are getting.I hope you followed the blog post i have shared in another thread. so it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the governance registry to initialize the ServiceManager.

ServiceManager serviceManager = new ServiceManager(governanceRegistry);

Service[] services = serviceManager.getAllServices();

[1]http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Services+with+Governance+API

-Ajith

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am working in the Identity Server 4.1.0. I added a Resource in the registry from the Management-Console (Web-Frontend) in this path:
/_system/local/repository
The resource is called apacheInfo.
Inside the resource I added a Property with
key = com.xxx.identity.Apache
value = www.domain.com:8998
my code:

```
CarbonContext cCtx = CarbonContext.getCurrentContext();
//this implies the path /_system/local/
Registry registry = cCtx.getRegistry(RegistryType.LOCAL_REPOSITORY);
Resource resource;
String apacheUrl;
            try {
                resource = registry.get("repository/apacheInfo");
                apacheUrl = resource.getProperty("com.xxx.identity.Apache");
            } catch (RegistryException e) {
                LOG.error("RegistryException looking up path repository/apacheInfo", e);
            }
```

I never found an example in the WSO2 documentation, but I saw this conversation:
http://wso2-oxygen-tank.10903.n7.nabble.com/Generic-Resource-Registry-Management-in-App-Factory-td79279.html

and then I understood the way how they read the repositories...
Hope this helps