# WS02 ESB - How to get Custom java class property file on the classpath

Tags: groovy, classpath, mediator, wso2-esb

I have loaded a custom jar file into WSO2 by placing it into the /repository/components/lib directory, performing a restart.  I then call that class from a script mediator using inline groovy.  The groovy script recognizes the class, however the custom class is attempting to load a properties file that must be on the classpath.  I have put that property file nearly everywhere but I keep getting an error that it cannot find the file on the classpath.

I am running the standalone WSO2 ESB 4.7.0.  I have put the file as part of the jar, I have also attempted to place it in several directories within the WSO2 file structure as well.  All to to avail.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to register a resource in the carbon registry and add a Property to this Resource. Basically there are two ways (in java...):
Here is an example how to connect to the registry via a service with the PropertiesAdminServiceStub: http://www.massapi.com/class/org/wso2/carbon/registry/properties/stub/PropertiesAdminServiceStub.java.html
The most important here is that you authenticated your user, the result is a cookie which yoou have to add to the stub.
The other would be something like this (probably a duplicate of your question)
[I am unable to get the list of services with in the applicaton i.e.; wso2 governance registry? I am working with binary code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091482/i-am-unable-to-get-the-list-of-services-with-in-the-applicaton-i-e-wso2-govern)
The last one asumes that the carbon-context is available, means you are running the search inside the wso2 like a feature for example.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no place to put that properties file.  Luckily this jar file, is an in house entity. It was written to search the classpath for the properties file and upon not finding one on the classpath to throw an exception.  We ended up rewriting the code that loads the properties file to upon not finding the file on the classpath to search in a directory which we specified as a system environment variable in the wso2server.sh file.  Not very elegant, but it is working perfectly.